# Как мне натянуть сверстанный дизайн уже на готовую тему Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть [сайт](http://www.AlkoNarkoStop.com.ua) на базе Wordpress с использованием премиум темы Enfold, которая адаптивная. И есть готовый макет дизайна. Мне нужно сверстать HTML и CSS стили, чтобы было в макете. Я сейчас этим и занимаюсь... Как мне натянуть сверстанный дизайн уже на готовую тему Enfold, чтобы не создавать новую тему, и чтобы сохранилась адаптивность? Какие мои действия? Как мне это реализовать?

Заранее спасибо, буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 2):

Внесение изменений в тему делается через [дочерние темы](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). Фактически, вам всё равно потребуется делать свою тему. Просто не с нуля, а переопределяя то, что вас не устраивает в текущей.

Comment: +1. Я уточню - нужно будет переделать только несколько шаблонов http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Блииин. а вопрос-то древний..Вряд ли ТС всё ещё ждет ответа. :) Ну хоть для других полезен будет.